# Symfony3 subdomain redirect

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, subdomain, yaml, symfony

I have a domain which enters the main page of the Symfony3-application, e.g.:

```
http://www.domain.ext/ => /app.php/
```

But I'd like to "invisibly redirect" (like in mod_rewrite) a subdomain to another path in my application, e.g.:

```
http://subdomain.domain.ext/ => /app.php/path/for/subdomain/
http://subdomain.domain.ext/otherpath/ => /app.php/path/for/subdomain/otherpath/
```

I already used routing.yml to try to catch the (dynamic!) subdomain:

```
redirect_subdomain:
   path: /
   host: "{subdomain}.{domain}"
   defaults:
      _controller: AppBundle:Redirecting:subdomain
      domain: '%domain%'
      subdomain: www
   requirements:
      domain: '%domain%'
      subdomain: !(local|www)
```

He never reaches the controller function.
I've used this page as reference: https://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html#testing-your-controllers.

Have I forgotton something? Do I still need to define the subdomain somewhere else in the php- or yml-files to make it work?